Failed to write sessions on VPS
The server worked fine, but suddenly I got this error when I try to access to phpMyAdmin:
Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_write_close(): Write failed: No space left on device (28)

session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/sessions)



Looks like your disk is full

@matigo, I remove files from  www/mywebSite for example, it should work ?

@matigo, or  which directories should be cleaned ?

Without knowing how your server is configured, I cannot answer the question honestly. Check that your log directories are not too large, and clear any temporary directories your web applications may use. This will rely on your knowledge of the software on the server.
